# Need help applying Implicit Eulers Method together with Newtons Method on Burgers' Equation

Tags: python, numerics

From the inviscid Burgers' equation: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$, I get the discretization $\frac{u_i^{n+1}-u_i^n}{\Delta t}+\frac{(u_i^{n+1})^2-(u_{i-1}^n)^2}{\Delta x}=0$. Having the starting conditions $u_0(x)=sin(\pi x)$, $x\in[0,1]$, I wish to plot $u$ after $n$ timesteps. However, I cannot seem to get it to work and would appreciate any help. Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres

#x
x0 = 0 #x min
xe = 1 #x max
N = 100 #Nodes
dx = (xe-x0)/N 
x = py.linspace(x0,xe,N)

#t
t0 = 0 #time
te = 1 #max time
dt = 0.0001 #timestep
M = int((te-t0)/dt) #timesteps

#u
u0 = py.sin(py.pi*x)

ts = 50

def EulerMethod(ustart):
    U = np.zeros((N,M))
    U[:,0] = ustart
    t=t0
    for i in range(N-1): #one step Euler forward
        U[0,1] = 0
        U[i+1,1] = U[i+1,0] - (dt/dx)*(U[i+1,0]**2-U[i,0]**2)
    for n in range(ts):
         U[:,n+2] = NewtonMethod(U[:,n+1],U[:,n]) #Eulers implicit method with Newtons Method        
         t=t+dt
    return U

def NewtonMethod(u,c):
    #c = u_n
    for i in range(3):
        F = np.zeros((N,1))
        J = np.zeros((N,N))
        J[N-1,N-1] = 1/dt + u[N-1]/dx
        F[0] = (u[0] - c[0])/dt + (u[0]**2)/2*dx
        for j in range(N-1):
            J[j,j] = 1/dt + u[j]/dx
            J[j+1,j] = 1/dt + u[j]/dx
            F[j+1] = (u[j+1] - c[j+1])/dt + (u[j+1]**2 - u[j]**2)/2*dx
        du = gmres(J,-F)[0]
        u = u + du
    return u

UM = EulerMethod(u0)
plt.plot(x,UM[:,ts])
```

Comment: I would suggest writing out the math of what you are trying to accomplish so that we can read it. Because from a glance at your code it looks a lot like you're trying to run both forward and implicit Euler at the same time, but your forward Euler is also implemented incorrectly as far as I can tell.

Comment: I will try to reformulate it better. Forward Euler is just supposed to be done the first step and I have fixed that now. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: As something of a side note, your space discretisation in your first sentence isn't a consistent one. $(a^2_i -a^2_{i-1})/\Delta x$ is a one sided approximation of $\frac{d a^2}{dx} = 2a\frac{da}{dx} $. I also wouldn't call the time discretisation you've written implicit Euler, but rather some sort of time splitting method.

Comment: Yea, you also do not need to initialize with a forward Euler step if you're doing 1st order backward Euler.

Comment: I seem to get it to work using only forward Euler but it is backwards Euler with Newton's method I'm interestead in. I'm very new to when it comes to discretization of PDEs. How would you suggest a time discretisation for implicit Euler's would look?
Yes, you are correct in that I don't need to use forward Euler to initialize it.

Comment: Backwards/Implicit Euler discretises $ \frac{dy}{dt}= f(y,t)$ as $\frac{u^{n+1}-u^n}{\Delta t} = f(u^{n+1},t^{n+1}$, so all of your nonlinear terms should be at the new time step. Note that when you're calculating you Jacobian in the code, this means the time term (i.e. the 1/dt bit) only appears on diagonal. In the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$ you want your problem to look like $u^{n+1} = u^{n}$, and in the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow \infty$ like $f(y)=0$.

Comment: So in the end you equation should be something along the lines of: $$u^{n+1} = u^{n} + \Delta u$$ where $$\Delta u = -\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right]^{-1}f(u)$$